# Is there anybody think about White Noise's distribution function??

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationary-processes, noise

According to Digital Communication textbook, auto-correlation of a random process denotes the expectation of the random process multiplied by its time-delayed.
$$R_X(\tau)=E[X(t)X(t+\tau)]$$
where $$X(t) \mbox{ is a random process}$$

---

In addition, for a stationary random process $X(t)$, the power spectral density is the Fourier transform of the auto-correlation function
$$S_X(f)=\mathbb{F}[R_X(\tau)]$$

---

The white noise is defined by $$S_N(f)=\frac{N_0}{2}$$

---

Now, my curiosity was aroused. What is the ***p.d.f***, ***c.d.f.*** or ***m.g.f.*** with regard to the White noise?

Therefore, I proceeded reversely.

$$R_X(\tau)=\mathbb{F}^{-1}[S_X(f)]=\frac{N_0}{2}\delta(\tau)$$

$$\therefore E[X(t)X(t+\tau)]=\delta(\tau)$$

My progress of finding $X(t)$ is stopped here.

Because I don't know how to solve that equation, I am trying to guess $X(t)$ and then show that the equation is correct or not through substitution.

Can someone give me any hints or good links about this problem?

Maybe, I should've just accept without any curiosities. Thanks to this curiosity, there is little progress of communication. Damn :(

Comment: I don't understand what you are searching for. the pdf,cdf,mgf of which random variable ? and for a discrete random process ($t \in \mathbb{Z})$  : $\mathbb{E}(X(n) X(n+m)) = \delta(m)$ means that the $X(n)$ are not correlated, i.e. that a realization of $(X(n))_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ will be white noise.  and if you are searching for a continuous time white noise there is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process whose "derivative" is in some sense continuous time white noise.

Comment: and note that any i.i.d. process with $0$ mean is white noise, the pdf of $X(n)$ for a single $n$ doesn't matter as far as it is a $0$ mean random variable with finite non-zero variance ! (which implies that its power spectral density will be $\delta(f)$ )

Comment: I do not understand auto-correlation of $X$ equals $\delta(\tau)$ means that $X$ is not correlated. (You wrote,  $E(X(n)X(n+m))=\delta(m)$ means that the $X(n)$ are not correlated), I think it should be $0$ for being not correlated. In addition, I don't know why in signal processing, the auto-correlation is often used without the normalization, that is, without subtracting the mean and dividing by the variance.